# Entity Framework Core run seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core to create `AppDBContext` and `AppDbContextSeed`:

AppDbContextSeed

```
public class AppDbContextSeed
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<AppRole> _roleManager;

    public AppDbContextSeed(AppDbContext dbContext, UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Seed()
    {
        ...
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<AppDbContextSeed>();
}
```

program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        try
        {
            var appDbContextSeed = services.GetService<AppDbContextSeed>();
            appDbContextSeed.Seed().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

When I run `add-migration` and `update-database`, no data from `appDbContextSeed` is inserted into the database. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks Ok but what is the (expected) relation to update-database ? This runs on startup, you need to check if seeding is required each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your seed execution on the `Main` method wich is run only on application startup. If you want your seed method to be executed at the same time you execute `update-database` command, you need to follow the new feature of seeding data in EF Core 2.1. That feature adds a new method on entity configuration `HasData` which let you add some initial data.

This is an excerpt of [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) feature documentation:

> Data seeding allows to provide initial data to populate a database.
>   Unlike in EF6, in EF Core, seeding data is associated with an entity
>   type as part of the model configuration. Then EF Core migrations can
>   automatically compute what insert, update or delete operations need to
>   be applied when upgrading the database to a new version of the model.

I recommend you to read the documentation to know to use that new feature.

Comment: Thank you help me a lot (like)